# Topology on the (canonical) union of sets vs disjoint union topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $B_{i} \subset \ell^\infty([0,1])$, $i \in I$, i.e. each $B_i$ denotes a class of bounded functions mapping from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Let $d(f,g)=\sup_{u \in [0,1]}|f(u)-g(u)|$, $f,g \in \ell^\infty([0,1])$ denote the sup-norm and let $d_i$ denote its restriction to $B_i$, $i \in I$.

Define the metric spaces $\mathcal{B}_i=(B_i,d_i)$, $i\in I$. Which is the difference between the topology of the disjoint union topological space $\coprod_{i \in I}\mathcal{B}_i$ and the metric topology induced by the restriction of $d$ on $\cup_{i\in I}B_i$?

Is one of the two topologies contained in the other or shall we consider those as two different topologies on two different spaces? Is there a meaningful way to relate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you have two metric spaces X and Y whose metrics are "compatible" on their intersection. You could interpret $X \cup Y$ as "X glued to Y along their intersection". And you can construct $X \sqcup Y$ as "replace X and Y with two spaces X' and Y' which have empty intersection, then define $X \sqcup Y = X' \cup Y'$. So $\mathbb R \cup \mathbb R = \mathbb R$ but $\mathbb R \sqcup \mathbb R = \mathbb R \times \{0,1\}$, the space consisting of two real lines that are disjoint.

Comment: So, essentially, the co-product topology and the subspace metric topology (on $\cup_{i\in I}B_i$) have to be understood as two different topologies on two different spaces, correct?

Comment: Now, if we have maps $\varphi_i: B_i \mapsto Y$, which are continuous w.r.t. $d_i$ and $r$ (with $r$ a metric on $Y$), by the universal property we know that there exists a unique continuous  map $\varphi: \coprod_{i\in I}B_i \mapsto (Y,r)$ such that: $\varphi\circ \psi_i(x)=\varphi(x)$, for any $x \in B_i$, $i \in I$, where $\psi_i:B_i \mapsto \coprod_{i\in I}B_i$ is the canonical injection. Is it possible to also construct/does it exist a (unique) continuous map $\varphi':(\cup_{i \in I} B_i, d) \mapsto (Y,r)$ such that $\varphi'(x)=\varphi_i(x)=\varphi\circ\psi_i(x)$, whenever $x \in B_i$?

Comment: Yes such a $\phi'$ exists but only if each of the $\phi_i$ agree on the intersection. Taking the union of two spaces or "gluing" them along a subspace is taking a pushout of the diagram $X \leftarrow \text{subspace} \rightarrow Y$. The universal property of pushouts guarantees that such a $\phi'$ exists.